# How can I PIVOT this data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

First, sorry for the middling title.  Didn't have a ton of success on that front.

So - I have a table of data that has one row for each volunteer shift a person is scheduled for.  Many people, being generous with their time, have signed up for multiple shifts.  What I would like is to PIVOT this data s.t. I end up with one row per *person*, with sets of columns for each shift.  I've spent about 90 minutes on this so far, but can't figure out how to PIVOT without an aggregation function applied.

What I mean by this is that each person is scheduled for at least one shift, so each person's row would have their unique ID, their name, their phone number, and their region.  Then there would be a set of columns for Shift1 - role/status/start time/end time/etc. - which everyone would have filled out since everyone has signed up for at least one shift.  Then, the Shift2 set of columns would be populated for people who have signed up for 2+ shifts, Shift3 for people who signed up for 3+ shifts, etc.

My current table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[confirmexport](
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [EventType] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [Shift] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](39) NULL,
    [Role] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](22) NULL,
    [Phone] [bigint] NULL,
    [Region] [varchar](9) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

All columns but `PersonID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Phone`, and `Region` are shift-specific.

In an ideal world, I'd end up with a table that looked something like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[confirmexportpivoted](
    [PersonID] [int] NULL,
    [Phone] [bigint] NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](22) NULL,
    [Region] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [EventType1] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [Shift1] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [StartDate1] [datetime] NULL,
    [StartTime1] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate1] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime1] [datetime] NULL,
    [Location1] [varchar](39) NULL,
    [Role1] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [Status1] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [EventType2] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [Shift2] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [StartDate2] [datetime] NULL,
    [StartTime2] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate2] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime2] [datetime] NULL,
    [Location2] [varchar](39) NULL,
    [Role2] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [Status2] [varchar](9) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Except with as many sets of columns as necessary for my data.  OR - if that's a deal-breaker, I can definitely make do with 3.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance - I am super-confused and would appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 2):

Well It was hard to me to reproduce the whole table, so I've worked only with Start and End Dates and Times, but solution should work for any number of columns. You can test it in SQL FIDDLE

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb80f/36)

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max), @stmt nvarchar(max)
declare @Temp_Columns table (RowNum int, COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(128))

insert into @Temp_Columns
select R.RowNum, c.COLUMN_NAME
from
(
    select row_number() over (partition by c.PersonID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Phone, c.Region order by c.StartDate asc, c.EndDate asc) as RowNum
    from confirmexport as c
) as R
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS] as c on c.TABLE_NAME = 'confirmexport' and c.COLUMN_NAME not in ('PersonID', 'FirstName', 'LastName')
order by 1, 2

select @columns = isnull(@columns + ', ', '') + 
    'min(case when A.RowNum = ' + cast(T.RowNum as nvarchar(128)) + 
    ' then A.[' + T.COLUMN_NAME + '] else null end) as [' + 
    T.COLUMN_NAME + cast(T.RowNum as nvarchar(128)) + ']'
from @Temp_Columns as T

select @stmt = '
select
    A.PersonId, A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.Phone, A.Region,' + @columns + '
from
(
    select
        c.*,
        row_number() over (partition by c.PersonID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Phone, c.Region order by c.StartDate asc, c.EndDate asc) as RowNum
    from confirmexport as c
) as A
group by
    A.PersonId, A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.Phone, A.Region'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```